# Can we change an exe icon according to the current solution configuration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation, icons

I want to know if there's a simple way to change my exe icon depending on compilation in release / debug / other configuration.

IDE is Visual Studio 2013, source code in C++.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible using a combination of tricks.

Create an icon for each configuration and store them each in a folder with the same name as the configurations you use (like Debug, Release).

Use $(ConfigurationName) in a pre-build command line.  Create a batch file to copy the correct icon to the 'source' location.  In other words if the application icon is .\App.ico create a batch file: 'copy .\%1\App.ico .\App.ico' or similar. (obviously get the paths correct).

The batch will execute and overwrite the app icon with the custom build icon.
Change configuration and the icon can change.  Just make sure that all icons are the same size.

I have used this to copy a text file into my builds - cannot see why it cannot work with icons.